# Python - importing other python programs as libraries

Tags: python-3.x, import, shared-libraries, python-import, pythonpath

I am using FreeCAD.
FreeCAD offers many libraries as .so files.
Therefore, to use them, i just have to modify `.bashrc`, in order to include in the `PYTHONPATH`, the location of the library files.
Then it is all a matter of doing `import FreeCAD` and this works.
This is all vanilla right now.

However, there is another library that i cannot import.
When i type import Draft, i get that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Draft'
```

I looked up and there is no `Draft.so` in the library directory.
However, in the program's GUI - python console when i type `import Draft` it works.

I investigated why this happens. I typed:

```
import Draft
import inspect
inspect.getfile(Draft)
```

And i got:

```
'/usr/share/freecad-daily/Mod/Draft/Draft.py'
```

This is another directory.
There is even another folder in this directory, that contains all the Draft function calls, as separate python files.
(For example there is a method called `Draft.scale()`. Inside the directory there is a file called `scale.py`)

Is there a way to include all these python files, so i can use `import Draft`, and just works?

Perhaps is it a matter of setting a new `PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `'/usr/share/freecad-daily/Mod/Draft'` to your `PYTHONPATH`

In general, each subdir inside Mod is a package root.